# `rdist` variation for more specific comparisons

Tags: r, field

`rdist` does a great job of working out a matrix of all the euclidean distances between  two vectors of x and y coordinates.

However, `rdist` wants to compare everything which can give output beyond what you need if you need a few comparisons only. e.g.

```
df <- data.frame(x1=c(0,0),y1=c(0,0),x2=c(0,2),y2=c(0,0))

# df
# x1 y1 x2 y2
# 1  0  0  0  0
# 2  0  0  2  0
# where   (x1,y1) are vectors for the first points and (x2,y2) are
# vectors for the second points. We want distances between points 1 and 
# points 2 for each row
```

If we only want to compare `x1,y1` with `x2,y2` that lie on the same row then the following method is a killer:

```
library(fields)
rdist(cbind(c(df[,1],df[,3]),c(df[,2],df[,4])))
```

So my question is what is the best way to achieve this? I can think of:

```
library(fields)

df <- data.frame(x1=c(0,0,0,5),y1=c(0,0,0,3),x2=c(0,2,3,6),y2=c(0,0,0,9))
results <- apply(df,1,function(x) rdist(cbind( c(x[1],x[3]),c(x[2],x[4]))))
```

then steal the second or third row from `results` as my distances...

Comment: Do you really mean to have 4 columns and 2 rows or two columns and 4 rows? Are your columns the points, or the rows?

Comment: Does that mean your point 1 has two x coordinates and two y coordinates, or do your columns and rows both refer to different points?

Comment: ok i rushed my question sorry, the edit should be clear now

Comment: Much clearer. see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue comes from  having your data in an unhelpful wide format.

If you split your two points sets 1 and 2 into separate data.frames

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = c(0,0), y = c(0,0))
df2 <- data.frame(x=c(0,2),y=c(0,0))
```

Then your rows refer to points, your columns to the respective x and y coordinates

you can then use some kind of `lapply` / `sapply` solution to just compare row by row

```
#using lapply returns a list of matrices
lapply(1:2, function(x,d1 =df1,d2 = df2){rdist(d1[x,,drop=F], d2[x,,drop=F])})
[[1]]
      [,1]
[1,] 1e-10

[[2]]
     [,1]
[1,]    2
# sapply will simplify to a vector
sapply(1:2, function(x,d1 =df1,d2 = df2){rdist(d1[x,,drop=F], d2[x,,drop=F])})
[1] 1e-10 2e+00
```